# Ria services: simple >>object<< properties/fields not appearing on the client side

Tags: wcf, silverlight, poco, ria

I'm using Ria services,
My POCO object has **simple object properties/fields**. But they are not appearing on the client side.
Please help,
My POCO:

```
[EnableClientAccess]
[DataContract]
public class DataRow
{
   [DataMember]
   [Key]
   public int RowId { get; set; }
   [DataMember] public >>>object[]<<< FieldValue { get; set; };
   public DataRow()
   {

   }
}
```

I tried field instead property with getter/setter
I tried `>>>object<<< FieldValue { get; set; } (NOT ARRAY), IEnumerable<object>` ...
Same results.
**Using WCF I can do it**.
For ex. I Have this contract in my wcf service (for sharepoint)

```
[DataContract]
public class SPFieldValueStub
{
    //[DataMember]
    //public virtual int ListItemIndex { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual object Raw { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual object Formatted { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual IEnumerable<SPFieldValueStub> References { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual IEnumerable<object> Properties { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual SPFieldStub Field { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class SPListItemStub
{
    [DataMember]
    public virtual IEnumerable<SPFieldValueStub> Values { get; set; }

}
```

in service implementation I can read data from sharepoint list populate my POCO and return to client. After that I can retrieve POCO's on the client side via generated proxy methods and unwrap (unbox) objects to real types (works fpr me String/Uri/DateTime). I need to do so with RIA.

Answer (score 0):

Because [`Object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx) does not contain any fields.

Comment: How can I wrap values of any serializable builtin (or my custom datacontract) types?

Comment: @user1453867 I don't know what you're trying to do (and how you did it with WCF), but you can't serialize an `object` because it contains no fields. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720474/why-cant-my-operation-contracts-in-my-wcf-client-take-interfaces-as-parameters).